# feature engineering while making predictions using a trained ML model as a service

Tags: python, machine-learning, flask, deployment, pickle

I am trying to build a flask service that does prediction for a regression problem. I have the data required for building the model which has around 20 columns. Using this data I have built a good regressor model. But training the model on data, I have done a lot of feature engineering such as log box cox transformations, one-hot encoding, dropping few columns because of high multicollinearity etc and the number of features is 35 now. I trained the model on these 35 features, checked the performance and saved the model using `pickle`. I loaded my pickled model in the flask service. But now the inputs to the model is in the format which my raw data was, which has only 20 columns.

So, how do I do all the feature engineering to the new set of inputs? I could only save the trained model, but how do I all the feature engineering before passing my new data for prediction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature engineering work, once successful (after a number of experiments), should be turned into input processing code (part of the ML pipeline). This code, maybe after some refactoring, should end up as input processing code before input to the trained models.

This is typically supported with the pluggable architecture (like [`Pipeline` in sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) or [`tf.data`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data) set of classes in TensorFlow).